# How to solve issue in using Right , LEFT , LEN , FIND functions in excel

Tags: excel

When I'm trying to use Right , LEFT , LEN , FIND functions in excel I am getting wrong results as mentioned in the snapshot  also i cant find a right answer online

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract date from datetime value use `INT()` function like-

```
=INT(A1)
```

To extract time from datetime values use `MOD()` function like-

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

You must then format the resultant cells as desired date/time format or use `TEXT()` function.

[image]

Comment: thanks dear for your support , i got it

Answer (score 0):

Dates are numbers. So use `INT`:

- In `B2`: `=INT(D2)`, and apply a number format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.
- In `C2`: `=D2-B2`, and apply a number format of `hh:mm:ss`.

[image]